# Making a static web app in html5 and need an image to scroll within the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is hard to explain in words, but basically making a mock up app to demonstrate the functionality of a new UI we will be implementing soon. I'm and intern here, just started using this html, css, and jquery.

There is a list of items in the background image that has to be able to scroll up and down within the background and hidden if it leaves the div. Any idea on how to do that? The only thing I could think of for clarifying what I need help on is including a picture. The picture shows the app (I took everything out just to be safe) and those horizontal lines are a list. Right now it's all one image, but I will make another one that should scroll up and down being visible only in the div. Any ideas on how to do that?

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a handout or for someone to write this code for me. I spent a lot of time on the web trying to find a way to do this, but I could never phrase the question in a way that would get me the results I was looking for. I am new to this and have a basic understanding of all the things that are possible with these tools. Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, whether it be a method I could look into or a link to another site that can explain this topic in more depth.

html:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow:auto;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-image:url('images/scroll.png');
}
```

Comment: "How do I do this" is not the kind of question that will get you much help here.  You should make some sort of attempt, post the code that you're having difficulty with and follow these guidelines. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Even better would be to create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem with code.

Comment: It is sad that SO users rather shun new people rather then offering a helping hand. Especially when they even state they are new to this. How would you expect them to know what to ask let along make a jsFiddle when they don't even know the possibilities. -sigh. My upvote for the pure fact you made an effort and even included a "mock up" of what you need.

Comment: @Tony Just because someone is new doesn't mean they shouldn't do their research and make some sort of attempt.  Maybe they will google jsFiddle and learn something helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really generic version to get you going, the inside elements can be changed to divs or whatever but this demonstrates adding a background to an individual item, having text in it, having a fixed sized window, and allowing the content to scroll.

The key here is having your container set to "overflow:auto", the background moving off the screen should be applied to the element containing your "list item".

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lookitstony/3qgbh9xy/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container fake-list">
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div class="fake-list-item"><img class="smile" /> Blah Blah Blah</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 200px; 
    width:300px; 
    overflow:auto;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}

ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin:0;}

li {
    background-image:url('IMAGEURL');
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    padding:10px;
}

.fake-list { 
    background-image:url('IMAGEURL');
}

.fake-list-item { 
    padding:10px; 
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
}
.fake-list-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-image:url('IMAGEURL');
}

img.smile { 
    height: 25px; 
    width:25px;  
    content: url('IMAGEURL');
}
```

Comment: I see what you are doing. I didn't use a list because I am trying to place another image on top of the background and have that image scroll. How did you call your CSS code from the html file without any ID's?

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle check it out, technically you could do it with the list as well but I used divs since you mentioned them. google "css selectors" and you will see a bunch of different ways. I am using the tag as a selector, I have added some classes as an example of how to reference them with my update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the content of a div with fixed size to scroll when lager as the div itself, jsut apply the CSS overflow:auto; to the div. Or make the scrollbar always appear using overflow-y: scroll;

```
<style type"text/css">
#container {
    width:200px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; 
    background-image:url('path/to/image.png');
}
</style>
<div id="conatiner">
    [List of items]
</div>
```